# Process MultiPart Http Response in Angular 6 From Rest Service

Tags: angular6, jersey-2.0, multipart

I have below response returned as Http MultiPart Response from Jersey Rest Service.

It contains bytes from file and JSON object

--Boundary_8_814011817_1615901173024
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[Binary File Content ]

--Boundary_8_814011817_1615901173024
Content-Type: application/json

{"conversionError":false,"details":{}}
--Boundary_8_814011817_1615901173024--

The issue is , I am not able to process the response at Angular side
Whenever above response is returned , the Angular is not able to process this response .
Interestingly , there is no error in browser console. So I am not able to find what is the exact error that is causing this

Can anybody please help me here ?

Below is the code for Angular :

```
 //service where back end call is made downloadService

downloadData(someData):Observable<any> { 
    
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',    
        'Accept': '*/*'
      }),
    }; 
    return this._http.post<any>(this.backEndUrl,someData,httpOptions);

 }
```

**Component where the service is consumed : (downloadService.downloadData is a service call)**

The below compoent code is never executed . The calls fails in service layer itself

```
  downloadService.downloadData(data).subscribe(
      (response:any) => {//process response here},
      (err) => "
  );
```

Comment: Fix the server to not return multipart. Use base64 if you need to. Some clients just don't have the capability to handle multipart responses. It _might_ be possible but it will be more headache than just changing the server.

Comment: Or just return the file and add the JSON part as a header.